# Collaborator's name does not show up on push to my github repository

Tags: git, github, push

I set up a github repository at:

https://github.com/dtenenbaum/biocsynctest

I added the user 'bioc-sync' (who is also me with a different github account) as a collaborator on this repository.

Then on another machine which is set up to do commits as bioc-sync (that is, doing "ssh -T git@github.com" says "Hi bioc-sync!"), I clone the repository, make a change, and commit and push it.

That commit shows up as being from 'dtenenbaum':

https://github.com/dtenenbaum/biocsynctest/commit/dca8af1983157b19b9280f98d529a8fed04bdf15

I was hoping it would show up as being from 'bioc-sync', because that is who really did the commit.

Am I misunderstanding the way collaboration works?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well, and it was because the email address embedded in the commit is used by github to determine who performed the commit.

This page explains in more detail what's going on:
https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user

Fixing the user.email of my commits to match the email address of the correct github.com account solved things for me.